# Identifying the deepest folder in the tree

Tags: command-line, bash

Note - please don't downvote me because of the image. Its not a code in the image, its just a diagram which can be easily visualised there.

As you can see in this image, the deepest directory is "n2" within "a" --> https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7hEy.jpg .

With the script/command/cmdlet/program, I want to programmatically find out the deepest folder within a given folder and be able to navigate into it (or print the absolute path of that deepest folder!).

Any help on how could this be achieved is appreciated.

Comment: Given the image is clearly text, what prevents you from copying the text here and using code formatting like I did in my answer to your previous question?

Comment: hey man i get your annoyance. But when I tried to paste it as it is, it looked horrible and not in the format. I quickly glanced over the formatting tips but couldnt figure it out.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code on how to format code and output.

Comment: @Nish Please do paste the text into your question, select it, and press Ctrl+K to format it as code so it looks correct. That will make this question considerably better.

Answer (score 1):

Using `find`, `sort` and `sed`:

```
find . -type d -printf '%d %p\0' | sort -zrn | sed -z 's/[0-9]* //; q'
```

- With `find`:

  - looking for directories (`-type d`)
  - `%d` and `%p` are the depth and name (including path)
- `sort` sorts the lines numerically, in reverse
- with `sed`, strip the leading depth, and quit after the first line, leaving just the path of the directory with the greatest depth

So:

```
cd "$(find . -type d -printf '%d %p\0' | sort -zrn | sed -z 's/[0-9]* //; q')"
```

Comment: thanks for this. Appreciate your help in understanding the statement.